# how to find edge of movieclip on action script 3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

movieclips in flash have a Rectalge Zone . if we have a Circle shape and covert to movieclip , have a Rectagle Area.with empty area.

i want terminate this area when az drag any moveclip on my target movieclip.
when i use hitTestObject do now work good.

(sorry for my poor english)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use bitmap based collision testing in this case. Here is a tutorial:

http://www.mikechambers.com/blog/2009/06/24/using-bitmapdata-hittest-for-collision-detection/